# Saving manys Users and their Profiles at the same time in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How should be the format of array to save multiple Users and their Profiles?

There are two models, Users and Profiles. On profiles table I have the foreign key "user_id". I tried using saveAll command for this, but only the Users are saved and profiles table is empty.

Out of for (setting up the array):

```
$data = array();
```

Inside of for:

```
$data[] = array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    ),
    'Profile' => array(
        'name' => $name,
    )
);
```

Save command:

```
$this->User->saveAll($data)
```

Model Associations:

```
User hasMany Profile
Profile belongsTo User
```

Ps.: saveAll saves 10 users but not their profiles ;/

Comment: can you post the code you have tried? That will help us

Comment: Have you linked/associated the models together?

Comment: Posted.....saveAll saves 10 users but not their profiles ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my onw question guys.

There are 2 solutions in this problem.

First:

This code:

```
User hasMany Profile
```

must be changed to hasOne:

```
User hasOne Profile
```

Second:

If you have a hasMany relation, you need to create an diferent array, using numeric keys on Profile even if you will add only one Profile (Maybe you will add others in another time). Like this:

```
$data[] = array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    ),
    'Profile' => array(
        0 => array(           //NEW LINE ADDED!!!!
            'name' => $name,
        )                     //NEW LINE ADDED!!!!

    )
);
```

Sorry for wasting your time. The question will keep alive just to help another guy with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [save associated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)

```
$this->User->saveAssociated($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is working code from my app:

Controller Code:

```
public function add() {


        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Member->create();

            if ($this->Member->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The member has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The member could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_message_error');
            }
        }
                $countries = $this->Member->Country->fetchList();

        $title_for_layout = 'Membership Signup';
        $this->set(compact('title_for_layout', 'countries'));
    }
```

User Model Code:

```
  public $hasOne = 'Member';
```

Member Model Code:

```
 public $belongsTo = array(        

          'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

View Code:

```
<div class="row">
     <?php echo $this->Form->create('Member', array('url'=>array('controller'=>'members', 'action'=>'add', 'admin'=>false))); ?>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <h3 class="sign-head">Personal Information</h3>
        </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array('div'=>FALSE, 'required'=>TRUE, 'placeholder'=>'username')); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('div'=>FALSE, 'required'=>TRUE, 'placeholder'=>'Password')); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Member.first_name', array('div'=>FALSE, 'required'=>TRUE, 'placeholder'=>'Name')); ?>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                     <?php echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array('div'=>FALSE, 'class'=>' submit-contact')); ?>
                  </div>

          <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
                </div>
```

Hope this help to other user.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $user = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password

     );
     $this->User->save($user);

  $profile = array(
        'name' => $name);
     $this->Profile->save($profile);
```

> you have to create a profile Model

Comment: But I want to save in a transaction. If one fail, all fail.  And this solution din't associate the user_id.

Comment: or you dont have create a profile controller or Model, you already got the information for the user. write a membre_index function and use the information from users table...

Comment: CakePHP supports transactions but you have to use the explicitly see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html